# How to get individual values and keys from JSON output?

Tags: python

My application needs to make a request and then treat the input so o I can get the individual values. My input will be something like

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "num": 11,
      "wo": "foo",
      "er": "ho",
    }
]
}
```

How can I use python to get the individual values and keys? My code is like

```
response = requests.request('GET', url, data='payload', headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

this prints all the structure I showed. Does anyone have any idea how I can get individual values? I checked the documentation and it says nothing about it.

Comment: Consider going through the standard [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), especially the parts about list and dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving data in JSON format so you can use the `json()` decoder built in to `requests`. It will turn your JSON data into a dictionary inside a list:

```py
response = requests.request('GET', url, data='payload', headers=headers)
data = response.json()['data'][0]
print(data['num'])
print(data['wo'])
print(data['er'])
```

Comment: actually, the `data` value in the request is irrelevant here too because it's a GET. It could be `response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers)`.